# Search a part of string using regular expression with dynamic values

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
{"rendererOptions":{"localeStrings":{"renderError":"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.","computeError":"An error occurred computing the PivotTable results.","uiRenderError":"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI.","selectAll":"Select All","selectNone":"Select None","tooMany":"(too many to list)","filterResults":"Filter values","apply":"Apply","cancel":"Cancel","totals":"Totals","vs":"vs","by":"by"},"rowSubtotalDisplay":{"hideOnExpand":true}},"localeStrings":{"renderError":"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.","computeError":"An error occurred computing the PivotTable results.","uiRenderError":"An error occurred rendering the PivotTable UI.","selectAll":"Select All","selectNone":"Select None","tooMany":"(too many to list)","filterResults":"Filter values","apply":"Apply","cancel":"Cancel","totals":"Totals","vs":"vs","by":"by"},"derivedAttributes":{},"hiddenAttributes":[],"hiddenFromAggregators":[],"hiddenFromDragDrop":[],"menuLimit":500,"cols":["clientname","industry"],"rows":["country"],"vals":[],"rowOrder":"key_a_to_z","colOrder":"key_a_to_z","exclusions":{},"inclusions":{},"unusedAttrsVertical":85,"autoSortUnusedAttrs":false,"onRefresh":null,"showUI":true,"sorters":{},"rendererName":"Table With Subtotal","inclusionsInfo":{},"aggregatorName":"Count"}
```

Within this, I want to extract the part of the string that begins with the word `cols:[]`. Values within the square brackets are going to be dynamic and enclosed in double quotes. For e.g. in the example above, the string I want to get is: `"cols":["clientname","industry"]`. Note: I don't have control over the number of values within the square brackets.

I wrote this regular expression: `("cols":\[("\w*",*\])|("cols":\["\w*"\]*))`
but obviously, I am doing something wrong. I need some hint to match either 1 or many values within the square brackets.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting. I should have been careful about the rules. No excuse. I know.

Comment: I think what you need to do is use a JSON parser and stop trying to kludge it with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !
**Regex :**

```
.*\"cols\":\[\"([^:]+)\"\]
```

**Output :**
[image]